# Scala - how to create a wrapper class without wrapping all methods

Tags: scala, wrapper

I have a 3rd party class which I can't modify. I want to add a `retry` functionality transparently. So caller doesn't know that retry is happening behind the scene. There are 2 kinds of 3rd party classes I encountered. One that I can extend and one that I cannot (private or protected).
For one that I cannot extend here's my soln:

```
class 3rdPartyClassA {
  def doSomething()
} 

class MyAppClassA {
  val 3rdpartyobjA = new 3rdPartyClassA()
  def doSomething() {
    Retry.retry(3rdpartyobjA.doSomething()) //wrapping 3rdparty call with retry
  }
}

object ClientFactory {
  def get3rdPartyclassA() = new MyAppClassA
}

class CallerCode {
  ClientFactory.get3rdPartyclassA().doSomething() //doSomething is called with Retry
}
```

In above solution, I have to create a wrapper method for every method in `3rdPartyClassA`. Even if I can extend `3rdPartyClassA` I have to override every method to add `Retry` logic.
Is there a way to avoid this? Like runtime I can say every method call of this class should be wrapped with my `Retry` logic. If so, what would be downside of that solution?

Comment: You can take a look at Java's Dynamic proxies: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html or any AOP framework like AspectJ.

Comment: Why? Runtime reflection should be discouraged

Comment: This is an intriguing one. It'd be nice to find a way without resorting to meta-programming or macros.

Answer (score 1):

There's no straightforward solution to this. You can use the `Dynamic` trait and invoke the underlying object's method using reflection.
https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Dynamic.html
But if you do it that way, type safety goes out of the window, which will not only lead to bugs but also degrade performance and make IDEs useless. I'd rather live with the wrapping boilerplate than taking this approach.

You could also implement `selectDynamic` with a macro, which would at least restore type safety. But that's also a bad idea because macros in their current form are going away in Scala 3. For good reasons, I might add.

Another possibility is to write a source code generator that will generate the boilerplate using reflection. Here's some information on how integrate this with sbt:
https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html
But unless the wrapped classes' API is very large, it's probably faster to just bite the bullet and write the boilerplate by hand.